# Bootstrap tooltips going off of page based on full width

Tags: html

I created some tooltips that can be changed using JQuery, and checked my code several times. I figured out the code was broken in CSS, as the width is incorrect. You can find a demo [here](http://codepen.io/TheGenieOfTruth/pen/zqPogQ) or just view it below

**HTML**

```
<body id = "body" style = "background:rgb(9,9,9)" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<p id = "intro" title = "test" data-toggle = "tooltip" data-placement = "right">Hello!!!</p>
<br/>
<br/>
<p id = "choice1" data-toggle = "tooltip">Herp a derp</p>
<script>
</script></body>
```

There is no CSS, and the only JQuery is that enabling the tooltips. 
**RECAP:** I have some tooltips that aren't working properly. Instead of appearing close to the original element, they try using the full width and appear across the page or in the middle. I'm trying to get the tooltips to do what they are supposed to do- Be next to the element they are tethered to and explain it when hovered, not explain it from halfway across the screen.

Comment: What do you want and what is happening that you dont like, the problem isn't clear at the moment,

Comment: Read the recap! It should explain what I'm trying to get done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p>` is not an inline element. Notice in the [Bootstrap documentation for Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) that they're only using it with `<a>` and `<button>` elements. You can do the following to make it work:

```
<p id="intro">
    <span title = "test" data-toggle = "tooltip" data-placement = "right">
      Hello!!!
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: I've been using BS Tooltips for while and pointing out that this has been demo'ed on inline elements is a blessing ! This should be mentionned in the docs imho